# Is there a better way to encode a (MS) DateTime as an Int?

Tags: datetime, drop-down-menu, type-conversion

BACKGROUND (ok to ignore/skip):

I feel like there should be a better way to do what I'm doing, but I don't know what it is and I think my solution works, but I thought I'd ask in case there is something more elegant or faster or whatever.

I am developing a web page with MS Razor MVC which uses Html.DropDownList, which gives a pick list UI control which maps choices as display strings to integer ID codes. (I don't *think* I can have it map strings to DateTime values.)

But in a couple of cases, I want to choose from dates that are stored as DateTime objects. I realize I could make yet another table in memory that relates ID codes to DateTime values, but I thought instead (and also because I think I may want to encode dates as ints for yet another workaround of web page annoyances), I would encode the date as an int.

PROBLEM:

How best to convert the date of a DateTime object as an int value, and then later set a DateTime's date back to that date from the encoded int. The main ugliness of my solution is that DateTime provides a read-only DayOfYear function, but no way I know of to set a date back to (Date, DayOfYear), so I wrote a method with a loop, which is cute but probably slowish.

MY CURRENT (OK) SOLUTION:

```
    public int encodeDate(DateTime date)
    {
        return ((date.Year - 2012) * 400) + date.DayOfYear;
    }

    public DateTime decodeDateCode(int dateCode)
    {
        int year = (dateCode / 400) + 2012;
        int day = dateCode % 400;
        // MS DateTime doesn't provide a direct reverse conversion for DayOfYear, so find it:
        int month = 1;
        int mThresh = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
        while (day > mThresh)
        {
            day -= mThresh;
            month++;
            mThresh = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
        }
        DateTime dateValue = new DateTime(year, month, day);
        return dateValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ho about to format the timestamp as POSIX time (POSIX time / Unix time, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)?

I had a similar problem myself and found a great solution here: [Convert a Unix timestamp to a .NET DateTime](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/07/10/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-a-.net-datetime.aspx)

From the link:

```
DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(double timestamp)
{

}


double ConvertToUnixTimestamp(DateTime date)
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. That should execute more quickly, and since it only lives for a web session and is about current events, it could also be ticks since a more recent year than 1970.